# Select row without checkbox being checked

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I'm using ag-grid:
https://www.ag-grid.com

I've tried the following grid options:

```
rowSelection: 'multiple',
suppressRowClickSelection: true,
rowDeselection: true
```

This results with rows not being selected when clicked...

And i try to achieve row selection (When you click on a row, the row will be marked) but without making the row's checkbox being checked...

Is there any way to achieve this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have several cheat options that essentially involve smoke and mirrors.

i.e

use a css style override on row focus

```
.ag-fresh .ag-row-focus { 
  background-color:white;
}
```

or do not show the row selection checkbox and instead show a checkbox with your own check in that you control yourself

Answer (score 0):

By setting these properties you should get what you want:

```
suppressCellSelection = true;
suppressRowClickSelection = false;
rowSelection = "multiple";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.ag-row-focus { 
    background-color:white;
}
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

All the above got me in the right direction, except I needed to add `!important` to the style to override the current css. I am using NextJS, threw the styling into a `.css` file, and imported it in the NextJS `_app.tsx` file.

So...

```
.ag-row-focus { 
    background-color: #ff0000 !important;
}
```